# How to compare siblings from the same group?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
<root>
   <applicant>
     <id>XYZ</id>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-04-01</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-04-01</end_date>
     </group>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-04-02</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-04-02</end_date>
     </group>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-04-03</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-04-03</end_date>
     </group>
  </applicant>
  <applicant>
     <id>ABC</id>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-05-01</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-05-01</end_date>
     </group>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-05-02</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-05-02</end_date>
     </group>
     <group>
        <start_date>2019-05-03</start_date>
        <end_date>2019-05-03</end_date>
     </group>
  </applicant>
</root>
```

and I need to group it by applicant and merge into one node with single start date and end date if date from from following sibling is 1 day different (date difference in days is 1)

so for above code to achieve something like:

```
<root>
  <applicant>
    <id>XYZ</id>
    <start_date>2019-04-01</start_date>
    <end_date>2019-04-03</end_date>
  </applicant>
  <applicant>
    <id>ABC</id>
    <start_date>2019-05-01</start_date>
    <end_date>2019-05-03</end_date>
  </applicant>
</root>
```

I was thinking about using following-sibling:: or some sort of recurrence.

Comment: If you can indeed use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, then I would remove the XSLT-1.0 tag from the question to be specific about what version you can use (especially because any XSLT 1.0 solution wouldn't be at all easy). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can indeed use XSLT 2.0 or above, you could use `xsl:for-each-group` here, and group starting with elements whose `start_date - 1` doesn't match the `end_date` of the previous group.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
     version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="applicant">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="id" />
      <xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-starting-with="group[not(xs:date(start_date) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') = xs:date(preceding-sibling::group[1]/end_date))]">
        <group>
          <xsl:copy-of select="start_date, current-group()[last()]/end_date" />
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(This uses XSLT 3.0. In XSLT 2.0, all you would need to do is replace the `xsl:mode` with the Identity Template)

Comment: Very good answer. I think that something should be said about the use of such special condition in order to not have a first non matching group.